# JPA doesn't recognize Serializable

Tags: java, jpa, serialization

I have the following classes:

Film:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fbId;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="year")
    private int year;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="direction",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="film", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Collection<Person> directors;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="genre", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="film"))
    @Column(name="id")
    private Collection<String> genres;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="release", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="film"))
    @Column(name="id")
    private Collection<Release> releases;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="trailers", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="film"))
    @Column(name="id")
    private Collection<URL> trailers;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="film")
    @MapKey(name="character")
    private Map<String, Performance> performances;
}
```

Performance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="performance")
public class Performance implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Film film;
    @Id
    @Column(name="film_character")
    private String character;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Person actor;

}
```

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fbId;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private Collection<Performance> performances;

}
```

Release:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="release")
public class Release implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="film")
    private Film film;
    @Column(name="release_date")
    private Date releaseDate;
    @Column(name="medium")
    private String region;
    @Column(name="region")
    private String medium;

}
```

When I test for something I get the following error, even though all classes implement Serializable

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: sw.film.model.Performance
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: Have you checked that `sw.film.model.Performance` actually implements `java.io.Serializable` and not a strange other `Serializable` class neither I nor JPA know a thing about?

Comment: And it is not really good idea to use objects, both as String, as an ID for database table. You better use digits for id to not have performance issues in future.

Comment: I think that was the problem... I'm kinda ashamed :(

Comment: and you are missing IdClass when having more than 1 Id field (which has to implement Serializable ... like the message tells you)